# Errors trying to submit VSIX extension to Visual Studio Marketplace

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-2022, vsix, vsixmanifest

I created a Roslyn Analyzer/Code Fix Vsix for Visual Studio 2022.  If I run it locally, it installs into VS and works fine.

I tried to submit to Visual Studio Marketplace and got an error stating: `Target 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community' with version range '[17.0,18.0)' requires specifying a product architecture`.

So in the .vsixmanifest file, I replaced:

```
    <Installation>
      <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[17.0,18.0)" />
    </Installation>
```

with

```
    <Installation>
      <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[17.0,18.0)">
        <ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>
      </InstallationTarget>
    </Installation>
```

However, now, when I recompile I get `Error VSSDK1062   Schema validation error for ... The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011:Dependencies' element is not declared.` and same for Assets element.  However, both elements are there in the file:

[image]

What am I missing?

**.vsixmanifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="AnalyzerFoo.67e73b27-47db-43ce-a4d0-b4a540217728" Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="Frank Rizzo"/>
    <DisplayName>Foo Code Fix for Visual Basic</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">Use Explicit Type code fix for Visual Basic (like in C#)</Description>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[17.0,18.0)">
      <ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>
    </InstallationTarget>
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5,)" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="AnalyzerUseExplicitType" Path="|AnalyzerUseExplicitType|"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Analyzer" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="AnalyzerUseExplicitType" Path="|AnalyzerUseExplicitType|"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="AnalyzerUseExplicitType.CodeFixes" Path="|AnalyzerUseExplicitType.CodeFixes|"/>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Analyzer" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="AnalyzerUseExplicitType.CodeFixes" Path="|AnalyzerUseExplicitType.CodeFixes|"/>
  </Assets>
  <Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[17.0,18.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices" Version="[17.0,18.0)" DisplayName="Roslyn Language Services" />
  </Prerequisites>
</PackageManifest>
```

Comment: ...does your extension _only_ target Community Edition, or does it have `<InstallationTarget>` elements for Professional and Enterprise editions?

Comment: Please post more of your `.vsixmanifest` file - we need to see your `<Prerequisite>` and `<PackageReference>` elements in full,

Comment: @Dai Added the link to the `.vsixmanifest` file.

Comment: What if you remove Dependencies?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov It still complains that Assets element is not declared.  If I remove that, then it compiles, but the VSIX doesn't actually include the Analyzer and the CodeFix.

Comment: What Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK and Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools package versions your project uses?